# How to add new number into each line?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, command

I have this line about 500 times in a my file backup.xml

```
my-company-review/</link>
```

Is there a way through command line, perl, etc. to add a number into the line after the word `review`.  For example, something like this:

```
my-company-review1/</link>
my-company-review2/</link>
my-company-review3/</link>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Perl, as I suggested with your last problem.  Once again, this is a sort of hack solution, that only works if there's a maximum of one replacement per line...  But it's a quick throw-away program.

```
perl -e '$count=1; foreach (<>) { s/(my-company-review)(\/<\/link>)/$1$count$2/ && $count++; print; }'
```

An extra loop will do multiple substitutions on a line:

```
perl -e '$count=1; foreach (<>) { while(s/(my-company-review)(\/<\/link>)/$1$count$2/) {$count++;} print; }'
```

That awk solution looks way nicer =)

Comment: That right there actually worked perfect for the question above.  I just tried using it for adding a number after the word `review` in `my-company-review</wp:post_name>` and no number was added.  This is what I entered:  `perl -e '$count=1; foreach (<>) { s/(my-company-review)(\/<\/wp:post_name>)/$1$count$2/ && $count++; print; }' backup.xml > newfile.xml` No error was given but the output file was exactly the same as the original...

Comment: Because the regex has a `\/` before the tag.  Take that out and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
perl -i -wpe ' BEGIN { $count = 1; }
               ++$count
                 if s{(my-company-review)(/</link>)}{$1$count$2};
             ' backup.xml
```

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'gsub("/</link>", NR "/</link>")' infile
```

or perl:

```
perl -ne 's:/</link>:$./</link>:; print' infile
```

Comment: This will replace with the same number if you have multiple copies on the same line.  Perhaps need to find a different record separator?